# Kotlin ArrayList returns data type when removeAt called

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, data-class

I have a Kotlin ArrayList holding a data class named TaskModel (e.g. `val taskModelList = ArrayList<TaskModel>()`)

But when I call remove at like `val taskModelList2 = taskModelList.removeAt(1)`, it return t as type `TaskModel` instead of `ArrayList<TaskModel>`. How can I get it to return an ArrayList of TaskModels?

Comment: why can't you keep using `taskModelList` ?

Comment: Why would it return an ArrayList? You're removing 1 item. You get the removed item

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get a list back, you could use `filterIndexed`:

```kotlin
taskModelList.filterIndexed { index, _ -> index != 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`apply()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html):

```
fun main() {
    arrayListOf("a", "remove", "me", "b", "c")
        .apply { removeAt(1) }
        .apply { removeAt(1) }
        .also(::println)
}
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c]
```